# where is the [Duration] attribute in mbunit, for timing tests?

Tags: performance, mbunit, duration

Is it gone from the latest version?

I want to see that a method doesn't deteriorate in its performance.
I forgot the technical term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the **[[Timeout]](http://gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_TimeoutAttribute.htm)** attribute. It might decorate test methods or test fixtures. The default value (when not specified) is 10 minutes.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Fixture
{
  [Test, Timeout(60)] // timeout at 60 seconds
  public void Method()
  {
  }
}
```